# Updating a boolean field in Rails through a JSON API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, boolean

I have a Settings table with 5 boolean fields. I want to be able to create and update those fields via JSON. From what I understand, Rails converts all parameters to strings, so that boolean values always return true. If I send:

```
{ "settings": { "setting1":true, "setting2":false } }
```

And then try doing: `Setting.new(params[:settings])`, both settings will be true in the database, since the second setting's value of `false` is translated to `"false"`, and thus actually evaluates to `true`. Actually I can't even do that, as I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<String:0x000000213dcbd0>)
```

on that line. Some suggestions from the internet say to compare the parameters against `"true"`, and then store that. This is a huge pain though, because then I can't take advantage of mass-assignment. I don't want to have to do this:

```
@setting = Setting.new
@setting.setting1 = (params[:settings][:setting1].eql? "true")
...
```

For all 5 fields, especially since I will have to do that for create, update, and even from other controllers (some controllers accept JSON to create a settings object along with their own attributes).

Is there a better way to go about this? JSON APIs seem pretty standard with Rails, it seems like this would be taken care of in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just making a convertor class and sticking it in a before filter?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter BooleanFilter
end

class BooleanFilter
  def self.filter(controller)
    # change all relevant string params to booleans, raise an exception if something other than "true" or "false" is detected
    # eg. params[:setting][:setting1] = ( params[:setting][:setting1] == "true" ? true : false )
  end
end
```

It is probably more consistent with Rails to assign the changed params to a new Hash object and to pass that to the model.

Comment: This is basically what I went with. I still think it's ridiculous you have to do a workaround in order for Rails to recognize valid JSON -_-

Comment: See my answer bellow, I think this is overkill, you can just use `"0"` instead of false.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass "0" instead of false to set the value of the field to false.

Comment: true. 
[won't work with .where(active: '1') eg though]